GCC can not load functions defined in dll.a library in windows: Calling Julia from C
I am trying to call Julia functions from C on windows. I followed the documentation from Julia and everything should work properly, but for some reason it does not. The main problem is that when I am trying to compile with the code bellow I keep getting  undefined reference for the functions that I am using from julia: _imp__jl_init _imp__jl_eval_string _imp__jl_atexit_hook.
    #include <julia.h>
    JULIA_DEFINE_FAST_TLS // only define this once, in an executable (not in a shared library) if you want fast code.

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        /* required: setup the Julia context */
        jl_init();

        /* run Julia commands */
        jl_eval_string("print(sqrt(2.0))");

        /* strongly recommended: notify Julia that the
             program is about to terminate. this allows
             Julia time to cleanup pending write requests
             and run all finalizers
        */
        jl_atexit_hook(0);
        return 0;
    }

the file is called test.c and I use the following gcc command: gcc -v -o test -march=pentium4 -I%JULIA_DIR%\include\julia -L%JULIA_DIR%\lib test.c -ljulia. The full verbose output I am getting is also bellow:
C:\Users\SComiati\OneDrive - DXC Production\Documents\c-code>gcc -v -o test -march=pentium4 -I%JULIA_DIR%\include\julia -L%JULIA_DIR%\lib test.c -ljulia
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test.exe' '-march=pentium4' '-I' 'C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\include\julia' '-LC:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\lib'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -I C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\include\julia 
-iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/ test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -march=pentium4 -auxbase test -version -o C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSKCncc.s
GNU C11 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\include\julia
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C11 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) version 6.3.0 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 384cad586f05ed581a9c068b2f18b408
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test.exe' '-march=pentium4' '-I' 'C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\include\julia' '-LC:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\lib'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -I C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\include\julia -o C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrWC7dD.o C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSKCncc.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.28
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'test.exe' '-march=pentium4' '-I' 'C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\include\julia' '-LC:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\lib'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Temp\cc24U3oi.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -o test.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtbegin.o -LC:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.11.1\lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../.. C:\Users\SComiati\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrWC7dD.o -ljulia -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/crtend.o

Anyone has any ideea what is going on?

There is some part missing from the above output. Where is the actual error message?

Welcome to Stackoverflow. The build log you have posted does not report any linkage errors at all. You will need to give us
a Minimal Reproducible Example

Also, gcc 6.3 is really old (like 8 full releases behind current). And is the julia library really built for 32-bit code, when all Windows versions are 64-bit nowadays?
